# How to get create your real-work simple server on Python

Tags: python, sockets, web

I am writing simple app with using Python socket lib.
I wrote a simple Server and Client. On my local computer is works. But I want to send Client app to my friend. The problem is here:

```
Server:
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
port = 3010
serverSocket.bind((HOST, port))

Client:
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
port = 3010
clientSocket.connect((HOST, port))
```

When this apps run on my local machine it is ok. But what HOST should be to make possible communicate with MY computer from other computer?

Comment: Try `"0.0.0.0"`

Comment: And what HOST should be in Client app?

Comment: the _global_ network address of your computer, of course.

Comment: I tried to use my IP. But it is not work. Client app error:socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Comment: how many programmers does it take to establish Internet connection? None, that's a hardware problem :D

Comment: Can you explain? I dont think this is a hardware problem. When I use HOST = socket.gethostbyname("google.com"), it works and Internet connection creates.

Comment: are you sure the host's using your computer's Internet address (e.g. not starting with `192.168.` and not `127.0.0.1`)? `socket.error` represents a system-related error, such as an I/O failure, which means that your code has triggered some kind of _system_ misbehavior and you as a programmer can probably do nothing about this.

Comment: No, I am not sure. What can I do? I just want, that my app works :(

Comment: well, it's often difficult to make code work... Google something like "check my IP online" and find some site that displays your server's IP address. Then use this address in the client app and see if it works.

Comment: I did it from the beginning. I went to websites, found my IP, and used it as parameter of function.

Comment: If your network interface address (on your machine -- as displayed with ifconfig/ipconfig) is different than the "check my IP online" address you get, then you are likely behind a NAT router. In that case, you also need to understand NAT a little bit and the idea of port-forwarding. Getting around this is router-dependent (and generally will be outside the scope of stackoverflow).